# C# How GOTO works in this example (Not as expected)?

Tags: c#, match, goto

This C# code is simple:

The scenario of this code:

When the word is matched it results unexpected output:

The word is found
The word is not found
The value of found is: True

When the word is not matched it results the expected output:

The word is not found
The value of found is: False

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] words = { "casino", "other word" };

        Boolean found = false;
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (word == "casino")
                {
                    found = true;
                    goto Found;
                }
            }

        if(!found)
        {
            goto NotFound;
        }

    Found: { Console.WriteLine("The word is found"); }
    NotFound: { Console.WriteLine("The word is not found"); }

        Console.WriteLine("The value of found is: {0}", found);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: I didn't realise `C#` even had `goto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goto statement just moves the execution to that point.  So in you case the Found is being executed then the next line, NotFound, is being executed.

To fix this using goto you would have to have a 3rd goto which is something like Continue.

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] words = { "casino", "other word" };

    Boolean found = false;

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (word == "casino")
        {
            found = true;
            goto Found;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        goto NotFound;
    }

    Found: { Console.WriteLine("The word is found"); goto Continue; }
    NotFound: { Console.WriteLine("The word is not found"); }

    Continue:
    Console.WriteLine("The value of found is: {0}", found);

    Console.Read();
}
```

I would much prefer something like this however:

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] words = { "casino", "other word" };

    Boolean found = false;

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (word == "casino")
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The word is not found");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The word is found");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The value of found is: {0}", found);

    Console.Read();
}
```

Or even better!

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] words = { "casino", "other word" };

    if (words.Contains("casino"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The word is found");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The word is not found");
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Pete, I know that avoiding goto is preferable, but I am just exploring how does it work.

Answer (score 1):

When you `goto Found`, all of the rest of your code will then execute, including the very next statement.

Comment: Thanks for help @SLaks, but How to rearrange it to work? (I know that goto statements is not safe.. but I gust want to understand its working with simple example).